# Getting an array of values from a form with array-named inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form, generated on a complex product page, which helps edit the products and its variants. Once manually changed, I have to get all the inputs from the generated form and put it back in the original inputs.

To keep it smart, if not simple, I'd like to name all generated inputs in the "array" style. 
Once the form is submitted, is there a way to easily "make" an associative javascript array with js/jquery ?
aka, I'd like to have :

```
inputValues = { 
  546is_article_id_4644 : { public_price : 20.02, provider_price : 14.90},
  car_id_size : { name : { old: "Sizee", new: "Size" } }
}
```

HTML + JS

```
<input type="text" name="f[article_id][public_price]"   class="f_in" value="20.02" />
<input type="text" name="f[article_id][provider_price]" class="f_in" value="14.99" />

<input type="hidden" name="f[car_id][name][old]" class="f_in" value="the old name" />
<input type="text"   name="f[car_id][name][new]" class="f_in" value="the new name" />
<a href="#" id="f_submit" />Test form</a>

$('#f_submit').click(function() {
  f_inputs = $(':input.f_in');
  // what to do ... ? 
});
```

Comment: use `.serializeArray()`

Comment: I need to work on the input values with JS, they are not meant to GET/POST the form !

Comment: Does your HTML have the strings `article_id` and `car_id`, or do these contain the actual IDs of the article and car?

Comment: the actual ids (like '546is_article_id_4644' for article id and 'car_id_size' for the car_id )

Comment: the ugly way would be to parse each input name (based on [ ] ) and reconstruct an array

Comment: okay, unless a great answer comes up, I'm gonna work on predefined keys.